# Credit Card Dropdownlist

Tags: paypal, asp.net-mvc-5

I a working on accepting payments with credit cards through PayPal, for the card type I have an enum

```
namespace AccessorizeForLess.Enums
{
    public static class Enums
    {
        public enum CreditCardtTypes
        {
            Visa = 0,
            Mastercard = 1,
            Discover = 2,
            AMEX = 3
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my form I have this

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardType, "Card Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Cardtypes,  "- Please Select -", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:155px;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

But everytime I run it card type is null. Anyone got a better solution that I can use for this?

**EDIT**

This is the model I'm binding to

```
namespace AccessorizeForLess.ViewModels
{
    public class PayWithCCViewModel
    {
        .... // other proeprties

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Card type is required")]
        public string CardType { get; set; }

        public Enums.Enums.CreditCardtTypes Cardtypes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the model your binding to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your property to

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Card type is required")]
public CreditCardtTypes CardType { get; set; }
```

and remove the `public Enums.Enums.CreditCardtTypes Cardtypes { get; set; }` property.

Then in the view use

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.CardType , "- Please Select -", new { .... })
```

so that your binding to the property of your model (the helper will generate an option for each value in the enum)

Comment: Thanks for the help, though this opened up another can of worms this issue is solved.